# How to automatically delete local files with FtpInboundFileSynchronizer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm synchronizing an folder using `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory()`.

Unfortunately only new files are downloaded, but files not present on the ftp are not removed locally.
How can I configure the class to automatically remove any nonexisting files also locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently supported by the synchronizer.

You could implement it with a couple of `FtpOutboundGateway`s; first use a gateway to LS the remote directory and remove local files that don't exist remotely; then use a gateway to GET the missing files.

You could also do it programmatically with an `FtpRemoteFileTemplate`.